# Read csv files in stream and store them in database

Tags: node.js, csv, stream

I have a few huge csv files, what I need to store in a mongo database. Because these files are too big, I need to use stream. I pause the stream while the data writing into the database.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var db = mongo.MongoClient.connect...

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('hugefile.csv');
readStream.on('data', function(data) {
  readStream.pause();
  csv.parse(data.toString(), { delimiter: ','}, function(err, output) {
    db.collection(coll).insert(data, function(err) {
      readStream.resume();
    });
  });
});
readStream.on('end', function() {
  logger.info('file stored');
});
```

But the `csv.parse` drop an error, because I would need to read the files line by line to handle them as csv, and convert to json for the mongodb. Maybe I should not pause them, but use an interface. I didn't find any solution for this yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I think you might want to create a stream of lines from your raw data stream.

Here is an example from the split package.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/split

```
fs.createReadStream(file)
.pipe(split())
.on('data', function (line) {
  //each chunk now is a seperate line! 
})
```

Adapted to your example it might look like this

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('hugefile.csv');
var lineStream = readStream.pipe(split());
lineStream.on('data', function(data) {
    //remaining code unmodified
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure if bulk() was a thing back in '15, but whosoever is trying to import items from large sources should consider using them.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect...

var counter = 0;        // to keep count of values in the bulk()
const BULK_SIZE = 1000;
var bulkItem = Item.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('hugefile.csv');
const csvStream = csv.fromStream(readStream, { headers: true });
csvStream.on('data', data => {
    counter++;
    bulkOrder.insert(order);

    if (counter === BATCH_SIZE) {
      csvStream.pause();
      bulkOrder.execute((err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        counter = 0;
        bulkItem = Item.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        csvStream.resume();
      });
    }
  }
});
```